# How to redirect a user to another page if the user already visit the same page link. (This is not a login page.)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

Please Help me ..!! **How do I do this now ??**

I want to make a `redirect WebPage`, where if a user comes the first time, then the user will see `original page`. But if the user visits or comes again in 1-2 days at the same page link then the page will automatically redirect to `another page link`.

(This is not a `login page`. It's just a simple PHP or HTML Web page.)

**Please Help me**, I want to do this.

Comment: Just check user with cookie

Comment: If you are using PHP you can just set a cookie and check for it on page load. If the cookie is present you can redirect to your desired location. https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it either in php or in js

**PHP**

```
    $cookie_name = "redirect_cookie";
    $cookie_value = "true";
    if (!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])){
      setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
    } else {
         header("Location: <url>"); /* Redirect browser */
         exit();
    }

?>
```

Comment: **Thank Your Brother** _it working_ But here i got a problem that is when the code Redirect to another link then there can not catch up the `click id` .
i mean if user click the continue button (physical click) then then landing make `click id` but when the code redirect the same link then the link or landing can not generate the `click id` .

i need the click id for my work. Please Brother remake the code for me.